# Get multiple values in diferrent JSON keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Good day,

This is my sample response in my API, and i am bit confused about the results. There are multiple objects in items array,  I want to get a specific response coming from the API. My question is how can i get the multiple values in multiple keys in JSON?

```
items: [ {
              "venue": {
                        "id": "4e82750f8b8185a7c93d3632",
                        "name": "Puregold Meycauyan",
                        "contact": {},
                        "location": {
                            "crossStreet": "Meycauayan",
                            "lat": 14.72670029378359,
                            "lng": 120.96040348293954,
                            "labeledLatLngs": [
                                {
                                    "label": "display",
                                    "lat": 14.72670029378359,
                                    "lng": 120.96040348293954
                                }
                            ],
                            "cc": "PH",
                            "city": "Bulacan",
                            "state": "Bulacan",
                            "country": "Pilipinas",
                            "formattedAddress": [
                                "Meycauayan",
                                "Bulacan",
                                "Bulacan",
                                "Pilipinas"
                            ]
                        },
             "tips": [
                        {
                            "id": "4f656942e4b08b4770548244",
                            "createdAt": 1332046146,
                            "text": "This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.",
                            "type": "user",
                            "canonicalUrl": "https://foursquare.com/item/4f656942e4b08b4770548244",
}

                    ];
}];
```

I will only get the venue.name, venue.formattedAddress, and the tips.text?

My expected out are:

```
Name: Puregold Meycauyan,
formattedAddress:  "Meycauayan, Bulacan, Bulacan, Pilipinas",
Tips: This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.
```

Comment: please clarify your question and show the expected output.

Comment: You can only get a 'limited' response form the API if you send it a request that returns a limited response. You have the result assigned to something like `var json` right? Simply access the relevant keys through the object notation (`.` or `["key"]`).

Comment: the JSON format is invalid now that you edited it

Comment: re your expected output: there could be more than one entry in `tips`, so how would you handle that?

Comment: Is _"My expected out are:"_ a string or a plain object?

Comment: Sorry  sir, 

this is my expected output: 

**Name: Puregold Meycauyan,
formattedAddress:  "Meycauayan, Bulacan, Bulacan, Pilipinas",
Tips: This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.

Name: Puregold Meycauyan,
formattedAddress:  "Meycauayan, Bulacan, Bulacan, Pilipinas",
Tips: This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.**

A plain text sir

Comment: @RannieOllit "Sorry" is meaningless and not relevant to the inquiry. Have you read the links posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657752/get-multiple-values-in-diferrent-json-keys-in-javascript/46657832?noredirect=1#comment80264659_46657832?

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring assignment to get and assign specific elements of array or object to variable identifiers

```js
let items = [{"venue":{"id":"4e82750f8b8185a7c93d3632","name":"Puregold Meycauyan","contact":{},"location":{"crossStreet":"Meycauayan","lat":14.72670029378359,"lng":120.96040348293954,"labeledLatLngs":[{"label":"display","lat":14.72670029378359,"lng":120.96040348293954}],"cc":"PH","city":"Bulacan","state":"Bulacan","country":"Pilipinas","formattedAddress":["Meycauayan","Bulacan","Bulacan","Pilipinas"]},"tips":[{"id":"4f656942e4b08b4770548244","createdAt":1332046146,"text":"This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.","type":"user","canonicalUrl":"https://foursquare.com/item/4f656942e4b08b4770548244"}]}}];

let {name:_name, location:{formattedAddress}, tips:[{text}]} = items[0].venue;

console.log(_name, formattedAddress, text);
```

Comment: sir, if there is a multiple venues and tips how? please see my updated post.

Comment: @RannieOllit _"if there is a multiple venues"_ is not mentioned at original Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What is expected result given an array of objects? You can use the same pattern when iterating an array of objects, though you cannot assign the same variable identifier to multiple different values. You could return an array of specific values.

Comment: same as above sir, but it prints the multple values

Comment: `let res = items.map(({venue:{name:Name, location:{formattedAddress}, tips:[{text:Tips}]}}) => ({Name, formattedAddress, Tips}))` should result in an array of specific values.

Comment: Sorry sir, this is my expected output: Name: Puregold Meycauyan, formattedAddress: "Meycauayan, Bulacan, Bulacan, Pilipinas", Tips: This grocery opens early and the lines are never long. Name: Puregold Meycauyan, formattedAddress: "Meycauayan, Bulacan, Bulacan, Pilipinas", Tips: This grocery opens early and the lines are never long. A plain text sir

Comment: Call `res.toString()` to convert an `Array` to `String`, alternatively, you can use `JSON.stringify(res)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your json is wrapped in braces, as well as the nested object in your array. E.G.

```js
var json = {
 "items": [{
      "venue": {
          "id": "4e82750f8b8185a7c93d3632",
          "name": "Puregold Meycauyan",
          "contact": {}
       }
    }]
}
console.log(json.items[0].venue.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the expected output could be done as follows:

```js
 var json = { 
      items: [{
 "venue": {
  "id": "4e82750f8b8185a7c93d3632",
  "name": "Puregold Meycauyan",
  "contact": {
   
  },
  "location": {
   "crossStreet": "Meycauayan",
   "lat": 14.72670029378359,
   "lng": 120.96040348293954,
   "labeledLatLngs": [{
    "label": "display",
    "lat": 14.72670029378359,
    "lng": 120.96040348293954
   }],
   "cc": "PH",
   "city": "Bulacan",
   "state": "Bulacan",
   "country": "Pilipinas",
   "formattedAddress": ["Meycauayan",
   "Bulacan",
   "Bulacan",
   "Pilipinas"]
  },
  "tips": [{
   "id": "4f656942e4b08b4770548244",
   "createdAt": 1332046146,
   "text": "This grocery opens early and the lines are never long.",
   "type": "user",
   "canonicalUrl": "https://foursquare.com/item/4f656942e4b08b4770548244",
   
  }]
 }
}] 
};
console.log("Name: " + json.items[0].venue.name + ",\n" +
"formattedAddress:  \"" + json.items[0].venue.location.formattedAddress.toString() + "\",\n" + 
"Tips: " + json.items[0].venue.tips[0].text);
```